# Android App Using Sherlock No Resource Identifier

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock

Hi so this is my first time making an android app and I am trying to use Sherlock Themes. When I imported everything per the instructions from Sherlock and after watching videos for importing Sherlock into the Android Studio build.gradle. I am finding an error that I am unable to fix. I will link the  error below.

error:

```
Error:(4) No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'test.test.test.unmfinder30'
```

Android Studio claims error is here app:showAsAction="never":

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I also have an cannot resolve symbol "R" which I am unable to deal with as well in my MainActivity.java.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;


public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

}

Please help me make the first hurdle in my noviceness for programming Android apps in Android Studio. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Vector,

ActionBarSherlock is now Deprecated! You should really consider using the Google-provided support-v7-app-compat https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that was definitely the issue.